# Clone and update many records Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to clone some 1000 records; change its Foreign key and insert the newly created records in the same table.

The below lines works well, but I think it can be done in one shot rather than iterating over 1000 records.

```
for scenario_driver in ScenarioDrivers.objects(ScenarioId=scenario_id):
    scenario_driver.id = None
    scenario_driver.update(upsert=True, ScenarioId=scenario)
```

How to clone and update many documents at **once**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `bulk_create` to implement this.